# cocoapods installtion on macos-catalina

Tags: ruby, cocoapods, macos-catalina, flutter-doctor

!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is
different from the one being used to invoke it.
This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
To re-install see
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
instructions.

cocoapods 1.11.2 is already installed and up-to-date.

ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]

Comment: Could you provide more details about what is the exact "not working" error-log or so?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.